# Django admin - fetch fields from form on delete

Tags: django, django-admin

I've overloaded delete() method of my model just to set 'deleted' flag and actual delete is not performed. But I want to add a comment with a reason why record was removed. So if I fill 'Comment' field in admin form, press 'Delete' and save model state it is not populated with a value of a 'Comment' field. Is it possible to put it into model when delete action is executed?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean that you overloaded `delete` method?

Comment: @alTus, thanks, it is true, I've fixed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [delete_confirmation_template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_confirmation_template) to display the form with comment field on confirmation page and process it in [delete_view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_view).

Also it would be more consistent than having the delete comment field in base form.